# How to add new accounts in one php file?

Tags: php

I have different user access levels, and I want to put their PHP code in one .php file. Assume that my submit buttons are named submit-*userlevel*

newaccount-handler.php

```
<?php
include('../connect-db.php');

//System Administrator
if($_POST["submit-admin"]){
    $username = $_POST['newuser'];
    $password = $_POST['newpass'];
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, position, username, password, access_level) VALUES ('$Name', 'Administrator', '$username', md5 ('$password'), '0')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die("error: " . mysql_error());
    }

    header("Location: home.php");
    mysql_close();
}

//Requestor
if($_POST["submit-requestor"]){
    $username = $_POST['newuser'];
    $password = $_POST['newpass'];
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, position, username, password, access_level) VALUES ('$Name', 'User', '$username', md5 ('$password'), '1')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die("error: " . mysql_error());
    }

    header("Location: home.php");
    mysql_close();
}

//BusinessHead
if($_POST["submit-businesshead"]){
    $username = $_POST['newuser'];
    $password = $_POST['newpass'];
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, position, username, password, access_level) VALUES ('$Name', 'BusinessHead', '$username', md5 ('$password'), '2')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
      die("error: " . mysql_error());
    }

    header("Location: home.php");
    mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="newaccount-handler.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
Username: <input type="text" name="newuser"> <br>
Password: <input type="password" name="newpass"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit-admin" value="Create">
</form>
```

**Notice: Undefined index** is my error. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to locate which section the error is in?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes. But it only display the error where the if($_POST[""]) is located. :(

Comment: That's important information! It helps you narrow down where the problem is... we're not mind-readers, we don't know where your error happened without you telling us :-) The next thing you should try is to work out which of `if($_POST[""])`'s have an issue.

Comment: @Patel Jignesh just fixed my problem. Thanks for your help tho. Appreciated it. :)

Comment: Yes, but you should also learn how to debug these things for yourself... you can't depend on Stack Overflow every time something goes wrong :-)

Comment: I'll take note of that. Thanks man. :)

Comment: *Wo*man :-) Troubleshooting is one of the most important skills you can develop as a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try like this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit-admin"])){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: When a hero comes along, with the strength to carry on. Thank you brother